# How can I use javascript to check and modify the height of two DIVs after a page has loaded?

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="a" class="grid_6" style="background-color: #ff00ff">
        <div class="block-border">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b" class="grid_6" style="background-color: #ffff00">
        <div class="block-border">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.grid_6 {
    width: 200px;
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.99%;
    margin-right: 0.99%;
}
```

How can I use javascript once the page is loaded to:

- Get the height of the DIVs with id of "a" and "b"
- Set the height of whichever is smaller to the value of the bigger one

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2QUaC/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it in pure javascript without any jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.document.onload = function(e){
        var aheight = document.getElementById("a").offsetHeight;
        var bheight = document.getElementById("b").offsetHeight;
        if(aheight > bheight) {
            document.getElementById("b").offsetHeight = aheight;
        }else {
            document.getElementById("a").offsetHeight = bheight;
         }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can place this code inside a script tag:

```
$(function() {
    var divAHeight = $("#a").height();
    var divBHeight = $("#b").height();

    if (divAHeight > divBHeight)
        $("#b").height(divAHeight);
    else
        $("#a").height(divBHeight);
});
```

The `$(function() { ... }` is used to delay the execution of the content just after the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks but we don't use jQuery :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  window.document.onload = function () {
    var divA = document.getElementById('a');
    var divB = document.getElementById('b');

    if (divA.offsetHeight > divB.offsetHeight) {
      divA.offsetHeight = divB.offsetHeight;
    } else {
      divB.offsetHeight = divA.offsetHeight;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how to do it with pure javascript but this is an example of how to do it with jQuery.

```
var heighta = $('#a').height();
var heightb= $('#b').height();
if(heighta>heightb)
{
   $('#b').height(heighta);
}
else
{   
    $('#a').height(heightb);
}
```

Comment: This isn't JavaScript. This is jQuery.

Comment: I will make sure questions have the jQuery tag or ask for it specifically before posting an answer with jQuery. I also forgot the onLoad part of the question...